# killall Dock - all active windows maximize and appear on Desktop

Tags: applescript, macos, dock, python, wallpaper

I have written python script to change desktop wallpaper.

After I change my wallpaper using the below code:

```
app('Finder').desktop_picture.set(mactypes.File(imageAddress))
```

I have added

```
os.system("killall Dock")
```

The wallpaper successfully changes, but all the active but minimized windows in the maximize.
My question is
 How do I refresh my Dock without changing the state of minimized/maximized windows?

Answer (score 1):

I know of no way to keep minimized windows from being restored when executing a
 `killall Dock` *command*, by any method.

The long workaround is to enumerate all application processes with visible windows and make a list of all minimized windows before executing `killall Dock` and then use the list to re-minimize afterwards. I seriously don't recommend doing that, but it's doable if you want to spend the time coding it.

That said, why not just use a method that doesn't require using `killall Dock` and immediately changes the wallpaper?

Here are two examples using AppleScript:

```
tell application "Finder" to set desktop picture to POSIX file "/Library/Desktop Pictures/Milky Way.jpg"
```

Or:

```
tell application "Finder" to set desktop picture to alias "Macintosh HD:Library:Desktop Pictures:Sierra.jpg"
```

From the command line, e.g. in Terminal or shell based script:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "Finder" to set desktop picture to POSIX file "/Library/Desktop Pictures/Milky Way.jpg"'
```

Any of these immediately changes the wallpaper without further need to do anything.

Comment: I have to still use `killall Dock` for the changes to take place. Even when I run the above from my shell, unless I run `killall Dock`, the latest changes don't take place.

Comment: @nakulchawla09, On my system running 10.12.5, the change in wallpaper is immediate and no need to use `killall Dock`.